# Which sentences are right

Tags: sentence-fragments

i have question. I would like to ask my friend something, he is on holiday.

First sentence: Do you have any interesting activities there? - or should i use have you got?

Second: Have you ever got letter from this country?

Are theese sentences correct?

Comment: With respect to your first sentence, both forms are grammatical. "Do you have any..." is proper English, where "Have you got any..." is colloquial. I don't recommend using *have you got* this way. With respect to your second sentence, I would prefer "Have you ever gotten a letter from this country?" though some dialects might use *got* here. In dialects where *gotten* is used, *got* is used alongside. *Gotten* is used for things that are received, where *got* is used for things that are possessed. Sorry. =/ (Note that the *a* I added is not optional.)

Comment: @MikeGraham In Britain we have not for the last couple of centuries used "gotten". The past participle of "get" is "got". This is further complicated by the fact that "got" can mean both "possess" as well as "acquire". This matter has been discussed at great length on this site in postings *passim*. May I suggest that anyone interested simply type "gotten" into the search bar. They will receive a host of references.